# How to create a context menu on datagrid and copy that value in winform

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagrid

I have seen many solutions about this but i didn't get proper answer. All answers are confusing.

```
contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Update", CopyClick));
DataGridViewCell ActiveCell = null;

private void CopyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (ActiveCell != null && ActiveCell.Value != null)
       Clipboard.SetText(ActiveCell.Value.ToString());

}
```

currently i am using above code and it will copy current cell value but i want like - if i select any row and press copy then `it will copy only first value from the row`.

so how can i do that?

Comment: press copy?? (ctrl+c or your context menu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
var str = YourDataGridView.Rows[ActiveCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
Clipboard.SetText(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet to copy the first item from your datagridview selected Row:

```
int ActiveRow = null;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick);
}

void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    ActiveRow = e.RowIndex;
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Show();
        contextMenuStrip1.Items[0].Click += new EventHandler(Copy_Click);
    }
}

void Copy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ActiveRow!=null)
        Clipboard.SetText(dataGridView1.Rows[ActiveRow].Cells[0].ToString());
}
```